# Adding a conditional column to a dataframe if the value is in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with a column called 'letters' that has letters of the alphabet as its values. So the first row could be 'C', next row 'Z', next 'M' so on and so forth:

### letters

C

Z

M

A

B

O

....

I also have lists that groups the letters of the alphabet by where they fall, so:

```
early_alph = ['A','B','C'....'M']
late_alph = ['N','O','P'....'Z']
```

I would like to to add a new column to my dataframe that groups the letters of the alphabet depending on which list they were in. If this was SQL I would write something like the following:

```
%let early_alph = ('A','B','C'....'M');
%let late_alph = ('N','O','P'....'Z');

create table my_df as 
 select 
  letters, 
  case when letters IN &early_alph. then 'early_alph' 
       when letters IN &late_alph then 'late_alph' 
       else 'unknown' end as 'Alph_group'
from my_table;
```

The output I would be looking for is:

**letters     Alph_group**

C            early_alph

Z               late_alph

M       early_alph

A       early_alph

B       early_alph

O       late_alph

I'm very new to Python and pandas, but in my research it seems like Numpy's np.where was promising, but every example I found tested against one value (rather than a list of values). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some of us don't really know SQL. Some expected output would help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.where` + `isin`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

*Set Up*:

```
letters = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')    ​
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(letters, 10), columns=['letters'])
early_alph = letters[:13]
late_alph = letters[13:]
```

---

```
df['cat'] = np.where(df.letters.isin(early_alph), 'early_alph',
            np.where(df.letters.isin(late_alph), 'late_alph', 'unkown'))
​
df
#letters       cat
#0    B early_alph
#1    Y  late_alph
#2    W  late_alph
#3    U  late_alph
#4    A early_alph
#5    K early_alph
#6    J early_alph
#7    C early_alph
#8    A early_alph
#9    C early_alph
```

Or another option, create a dictionary from the `early_alph` and `late_alph` lists that maps from `letter` to the categories and then use `map` method:

```
dd = dict([(early, 'early_alph') for early in early_alph] + 
          [(late, 'late_alph') for late in late_alph])

df['cat'] = df.letters.map(dd).fillna('unkown')
df
#letters       cat
#0  B   early_alph
#1  Y    late_alph
#2  W    late_alph
#3  U    late_alph
#4  A   early_alph
#5  K   early_alph
#6  J   early_alph
#7  C   early_alph
#8  A   early_alph
#9  C   early_alph
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with a nested where.

```
np.where(df.letters.between('A', 'M'), 'early_alph', np.where(df.letters.between('N','Z'), 'late_alph', 'unknown')
```